# Linux support on 2012 MacBooks

Tags: linux, graphics, macintosh

I want to buy a 2012 MacBook with the Retina Display. Does it work well with Linux?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, it's still very buggy, as per [this post on the openSUSE forums](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/laptop/476258-howto-2012-retina-display-macbook-pro-opensuse-linux.html) lots of stuff still doesn't works:

> What I have working so far:
>
> - Retina Display - openSUSE looks fantastic at 2880x1800!
> - Booting in emulated BIOS mode
> - Booting in EFI mode
> - Keyboard and Trackpad - full support including the function key on the keyboard, the keyboard backlight and multifinger support on the trackpad
> - Sound - this is a fantastic sounding laptop
> - 3D Acceleration - via the NVidia 650m graphics card
> - Sensors - including temperatures and fan speeds
> - Bluetooth
>
> What I don't have working yet:
>
> - 3D acceleration using the integrated Intel graphics card
> - Screen backlight control
> - Suspend and Hibernate
> - Built-in wireless card
> - Thunderbolt
>
> What I haven't tested yet:
>
> - Webcam
> - Card reader
> - External Monitor

Even if the hardware was supported, many apps are not (yet) designed for such high resolutions; as I understand it, OS X uses some hacks to get those working properly on the retina display.